# Getting error while using inlineImages

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-charts

I am always getting error while using inlineImages.

> Error
> Exception: Invalid argument: inlineImages"

Below is  my code:

```
var blob = Charts.newTableChart()
  .setDataTable(table.build())
  .setDimensions(1000, 1000)
  .setOption("alternatingRowStyle", false)
  .build()
  .getBlob();
 
var resultingFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);

var imagefileid=resultingFile.getId();
var ImageBlob = DriveApp
                      .getFileById(imagefileid)
                      .getBlob();

MailApp.sendEmail("dolatsang@gmailc.om", orderno, '',htmlbody:"<img src=\"cid:sampleImage\">",inlineImages:ImageBlob});
```

Please suggest something for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`MailApp.sendEmail("dolatsang@gmailc.om", orderno, '',htmlbody:"<img src=\"cid:sampleImage\">",inlineImages:{sampleImage:ImageBlob});`

- `inlineImages` is an object that maps from an image key (String) to image data (BlobSource).

  - Objects are surrounded by curly brackets. Your code had the "closed curly bracket" (`}`) but the corresponding opening curly bracket was missing.
  - Also the object requires the key and the data. You had the data `ImageBlob` but not the image key (`sampleImage`)
  - "htmlbody" references the image key (`sampleImage`)

References

[sendMail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app?hl=en#sendemailmessage)